# Trying to move cube when arrow pressed and swap 2 cubes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move a cube with an arrow key right and left in 2D mode of Unity.

I want to swap positions of cube with colliders attached but the code doesn't seem to work at all.

```cs
public float Jump = 0.6f;
Vector3 positionP, positionS, position, pos;
public GameObject Swapable;
public GameObject Player;

void Start ()
{
        positionS = Swapable.transform.position;
        positionP = Player.transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
                transform.position = Vector2.right * Jump;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
                transform.position = -Vector2.right * Jump;
        }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
{
        if (col.Equals ("Red")) {
                Debug.Log ("Touched");
                position = positionS;
                pos = positionP;
                Player.transform.position = position;
                Swapable.transform.position = pos;

        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? You need to elaborate more... Are you having trouble with your OnTRiggerEnter2D method being called? Are you having trouble with moving your cubes? or are you having trouble with swapping their positions?

Comment: Yea. I made OnTriggerEnter2D and OnCollisionEnter2D methods to detect the collision between two cubes but it seems that this methods just don't work in 2D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cubes are only moving to (0.6,0), NOT translating.

In your update method you call:

```
transform.position = Vector2.right * Jump;
```

Vector2.right ALWAYS returns (1,0). Jump is ALWAYS 0.6

So you're always setting your position to (0.6,0) whereas you need to increment it.

```
transform.position = transform.position + Vector2.right * Jump
```

Try this change and see if your cubes at least move now. From there we can try to fix any collision errors.

**EDIT:**

Ok, this will handle swapping for you. You'll want a master game object with this script managing the whole grid. When you want to swap positions, call the Swap function.

```
public class TilePositions
{
    //The objects in your grid
    public Transform[,] objects;

    //Offset from (0,0) that your grid's top-left is at.
    public Vector3 offset;

    //Scale of your grid
    public Vector2 scale;

    //Swap the objects at position one and position two in the grid
    public void Swap(Point one, Point two)
    {
        var temp = objects[one.x,one.y];

        objects[one.x,one.y] = objects[two.x,two.y];
        objects[two.x,two.y] = temp;

        objects[one.x,one.y].Position = new Vector3(one.x,one.y,0) * scale + offset;
        objects[two.x,two.y].Position = new Vector3(two.x,two.y,0) * scale + offset;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a transform's vector3 position to a Point struct
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The transform whose position is to be converted</param>
    /// <returns>System.Drawing.Point for the grid's position</returns>
    private Point PositionToPoint(Transform obj)
    {
        var position = (obj.Position - offset) / scale;
        return new Point((int)position.x, (int)position.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, i want to make it like on touch or arrow key cube1 moves to fixed position and the other cube2 take position of cube1. like candy crush that candy swaps it position on Collision or Trigger.

Comment: Do you want to swap the positions of the objects or move one of them to a fixed position? These two actions are not the same. What is this fixed position?

Comment: fixed is like grid of 4x4 or 8x8 blocks same as candy crush saga.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a fixed position, merely that your offset is fixed. I'll work on a solution in a bit for you.

Comment: Edited my solution, it should work, but you may need to make some alterations depending on the specifics for your game.

Comment: I'm glad! Please accept it as the answer using the tick symbol above :)